# How to pass parameters to node.js from Windows command line

Tags: node.js, windows

I'm working in a node application that can be started like this from a Mac machine:

```
DEBUG=app.* ENVIRONMENT=local node server/index.js
```

However, when trying to run that script in a Windows command line, I get the following message:

```
" 'DEBUG' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."
```

When running the script without the parameters, I don't get any error.

How can I pass said parameters to my index.js from Windows?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run this in the CMD window where you'll run your node app.

```
SET DEBUG=app.*
SET ENVIRONMENT=local
node server/index.js
```

Or if you want it to be in a single line, type this.

```
SET DEBUG=app.*&&SET ENVIRONMENT=local&&node server/index.js
```

To make this variable changes persistent, you should edit your environment variables in control panel.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: I know it's a little bit old post, but since I don't want to polute SO, I came here while trying to understand how to pass textual arguments to node... 

like this : 

node boot.js -verbose

From [documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv) that should just work.

The example only return me value 0 and 1 who are both the path of node and the path of boot.js...